# Execution of Entity Framework commands in a self-contained .NET Core app in Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core application that works perfectly within a Docker container. However, whenever I attempt to execute any Entity Framework command, like migration or database update, I encounter the following error:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'D:\GitLab\ExampleSolution\Example\bin\Release\net7.0\linux-x64\'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app.
  - The application was run as a self-contained app because 'D:\GitLab\ExampleSolution\Example\bin\Release\net7.0\linux-x64\Example.runtimeconfig.json' did not specify a framework.
  - If this should be a framework-dependent app, specify the appropriate framework in 'D:\GitLab\ExampleSolution\Example\bin\Release\net7.0\linux-x64\Example.runtimeconfig.json'.
Process terminated with exit code -2,147,450,749
```

In my normal `csproj` file, I have the following block:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>       
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
        <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
        <ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>
        <UseAppHost>true</UseAppHost>
        <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
        <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
        <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
        <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Through my research, I noticed that commenting out the line `<RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` allows me to execute the necessary EF commands in the Windows Rider terminal. This is because, without this line, dotnet generates the libraries required for successful execution. However, in this scenario, I'm unable to debug my app in Docker anymore, as it results in the following error:

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/app/bin/x64/Debug/net7.0/win-x64/'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app.
  - The application was run as a self-contained app because '/app/bin/x64/Debug/net7.0/win-x64/Example.runtimeconfig.json' did not specify a framework.
  - If this should be a framework-dependent app, specify the appropriate framework in '/app/bin/x64/Debug/net7.0/win-x64/Example.runtimeconfig.json'.
```

It's quite frustrating to have to comment and uncomment this line. Is there a way to build the app specifically for EF Core commands, or is there another well-suited solution?